# To know if mouse still hover menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following menu construction very resumed (cant change HTML code due is impossible, only CSS and JS!):

```js
$('span').on("hover", handleHover('span'));

function handleHover(e) {
        $(e).on({
            mouseenter: function() {
                $(this).addClass('selecc');
                $(this).next("ul").show();
            },
            mouseleave: function() {
                $(this).removeClass('selecc');
                $(this).next("ul").hide();
            }
        });

    }
```

```css
span {
  display:block;
}

ul {
  background-color:#CCC;
  color:#000;
  display:none;  
  margin:0;
}

.selecc {
  background-color:Red;
  color:#FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Option 1</span>
<ul>
<li>suboption 1-1</li>
<li>suboption 1-2</li>
<li>suboption 1-3</li>
</ul>
<span>Option 2</span>
<ul>
<li>suboption 2-1</li>
<li>suboption 2-2</li>
<li>suboption 2-3</li>
</ul>
```

I need to move the mouse over the suboptions but the menu closes and i dont know how to tell to jquery that UL is part of menu group. Some idea for this?

Comment: Wrap it with new container and listen to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No-one said you cannot **alter the HTML dynamically using jQuery** :)
So, yes, group your SPAN+UL into groups, and attach the hover function to your `.group` wrapper:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/faladu/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

```js
$("span").each(function(){
  var ul = $(this).next("ul");
  $(this).add(ul).wrapAll("<div class='group'/>");
});

$(".group").hover(handleHover);

function handleHover() {
  $("span",this).toggleClass('selecc');
  $("ul",this).stop().slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: it's a good trick to change HTML dynamically when can't change HTML code ;) thanks

Comment: Didnt know about "wrapAll" in jQuery and its a fantastic solution. Great and Thanks!